# Override the default content type of a document from a Visual Studio extension

Tags: visual-studio, editor, content-type, visual-studio-extensions

I'm writing an editor extension for Visual Studio. It assigns a custom `ContentType` for any file with the extension of ".abc". Here's the code:

```
    [Export]
    [FileExtension(".abc")]
    [ContentType("MyContentType")]
    internal FileExtensionToContentTypeDefinition MyTypeFileExtensionDefinition;
```

The content format of ".abc" files is actually a variant of XML. The problem is that when Visual Studio opens this file, it detects it's an XML file and therefore it assigns the ContentType of "XML" to the document, instead of "MyContentType" from my extension.

Is it possible to override this default behavior to make sure the ".abc" files will have the correct ContentType set, preferably with no action from users?

Comment: Did you try to delete the `bin` and `obj` folder and `C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\16.0_xxx\Extensions\<user_name>\<vsix_project_name>`?

Comment: @SaraLiu-MSFT I have tried uninstalling the extension and reinstalling it. It doesn't help.

Comment: create a new vsix project with another name and then face the same behavior?